# Control of directory listing in web browser with htaccess

Tags: list, .htaccess, directory

I would like to allow listing of directories by the server (apache), but only to files not to subdirs (in the listing, only file names must appear.) Is it possible to do this with htaccess directives or should I write my own application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`IndexIgnore` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignore) to:

```
# Hide the link to the parent directory
IndexIgnore ..

# Hide named subdirectories
IndexIgnore subdir dir-a
```

However, I can't see how you can "ignore" *any* subdirectory using the shell-style wildcard syntax supported by the `IndexIgnore` directive?

You can, however, use mod_rewrite and the fact that mod_autoindex issues an internal subrequest for each resource in the directory listing in order to suppress (forbid) subdirectories. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^[\w_-]+/$ - [F]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* simply ensures the resource "looks-like" a directory (yes, the requested URI appears to end in a slash). The condition actually checks that it is a directory before returning a 403 Forbidden. This is enough to simply prevent the subdirectory being listed. The 403 is not returned to the client, this is simply the response to the internal subrequest.

NB: Don't block the directory itself (eg. `RewriteRule ^ - [F]`) otherwise that will block your directory listing entirely.

> or should I write my own application ?

It depends how much control you want.

Comment: Thanks, these directives and rewrite rules allow appropriate control of the directory listing. No need for a specific application. I will invest in mod_rewrite, definitively worth for controlling a server.